# Signature of quadratic form.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

**In the space of polynomials with real coefficients of degree at most $n$, a quadratic form is given $Q (f) = f (1) \cdot f (2)$. Find its signature (number of ones and minus ones in normal form).**

I started to solve this problem as follows:

Each polynomial $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x^2 +...+ a_nx^n $ can be described with vector $a_f = (a_0, a_1,..., a_n) \in R^{n+1}$ . Then:
$$Q(f) = f(1)\cdot f(2) = (a_0+a_1...+a_n)\cdot(a_0+2a_1+2^2a_2+...+2^na_n) = a_f^Te \cdot r^Ta_f$$
where $e = (1,1,...,1), r = (1, 2, 2^2,...2^n) \ \Rightarrow$
$$Q(f) = Q(a_f) = a_f^Te \cdot r^Ta_f = a_f^T M a_f$$
So we get the matrix form $M = er^T$ of our quadratic form Q. However, this matrix $M$ turned out to be non-symmetric (it has $n+1$ identical rows equal to $r$), while the matrix of quadratic form should be always symmetric.

Could you please help me to understand if I am mistaken in something and how can this problem be correctly solved?

Thank you.

Comment: If you try the case $n=1$, you get $Q(f) = a_0^2+3a_0a_1+2a_2^2$. So you have to symmetrize your matrix.

Comment: Your matrix $M$ is not unique. In fact, $M^T$ is also valid, and so is any linear combination $cM + (1-c)M^T$. To get a symmetric matrix, you would take the symmetrized version $\frac{M+M^T}{2}$.

Comment: This is true,  I haven't taken this into account. Thank you very much!

Comment: First find the associated bilinear form by polarizing: $$B(f,g) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} Q(f+tg) = \frac{f(1)g(2)+f(2)g(1)}{2}.$$Now let $f_k(x)=x^k$, for $0\leq k \leq n$. We have that $$B(f_j,f_k)= 2^{j-1}+2^{k-1}.$$One approach is to diagonalize $(B(f_j,f_k))_{j,k=0}^n$.

Comment: Hint: use basis $\left\{1;x−1;\left(x−1\right)^2;…;\left(x−1\right)^n\right\}$. Then you can easily get normal form and find signature. If I'm not mistaken, both the number of ones and the number of minus ones are equal to 1.